# Delete FTP directory contents with CURL

Tags: curl, ftp

I have a directory "backup" on an FTP server. I want to delete all files in this directory using CURL. Is it possible? I tried:

```
curl --ssl ftp://aaa:bbb@ccc -Q "RMD backup"
```

But seems it only works on empty directory.

*Side note: I don't know the exact list of files in this directory.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using some shell script in conjunction with `curl`, you should be able to do this.  For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get the list of files in the directory.  Note that the
# trailing slash is important!
for f in `curl --ssl ftp://aaa:bbb@ccc backup/`; do

  # Delete each file individually
  curl --ssl ftp://aaa:bbb@ccc -Q "DELE backup/$f"
done

# You can remove the now-empty directory
curl --ssl ftp://aaa:bbb@ccc -Q "RMD backup"
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I created a crontab that runs everyday and delete the backup that is 10 days old. So since it runs everyday, there is no "old" backups:

```
curl --ssl ftp://aaa:bbb@ccc -Q "DELE sql/$(date -d '+10 days' +'%Y-%m-%d').sql"
```